# Custom objects in List of <t> change order?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am adding a bunch of custom objects to a List of Type. Can someone explain to me why the objects are sometimes retrieved from the list in a different order than what they were put into the list?

I am currently sorting the list on a custom property, which is fine, but it gets complicated to keep track of managing the order properties as to what should be where in the list.

I am storing usercontrols in custom objects, and rendering them on page init. Can it be that the browser/markup renders the controls differently. I don;t think this is it, as the markup should stay in the correct order, but because it is usercontrols, it might be rendered somewhere else, in a funky order. Thought it was worth mentioning.

My life would be far simpler if the list could just stay in the order that it was built.

My Questions:

- Why is the list not staying in the original order?
- Is it possible to
  force the original order of the objects?

EDIT

- **To the comments about code examples:**
  My question is not about why my sort code does not work. It is about the last two bullets above. This question is hanging more to the theoretical side.
- I am really experiencing erratic behavior, and could not find anything definitive in debugging yet. Is there a possibility that asp is changing the order of rendering my usercontrols? Which are the objects I am referring to being out of order.

Comment: List actually stays in the order it is filled. If you are facing other behaviors probably you are doing something wrong with your list.

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: To the downvoter, I would pay money to know what you are getting at... My question is perfectly valid.

Comment: Can it be that my objects are rendered in the wrong order? I am using them to render user controls. I am updating my question.

Comment: It's probably because the question is far too vague to answer with no code **at all**. Please post a short but complete program which reproduces the problem - I don't think anyone is going to be able to answer you with so little information.

Comment: @JonSkeet . Thanks for the comment. My code is quite specific and I doubt pasting an extract would make much sense. I might try to fire up something new, with the same constructs, to see if I can reproduce the problem. I think as trippino suggests, I might have an issue somewhere else if the list actually does keep order.

Comment: That's exactly what you should do - ideally getting rid of the ASP.NET dependency too. Or look at the list in the debugger at various points, to find out when it's being reordered. Basically there's a lot *you* can do at this point, but not a lot anyone else can help you with.

Comment: @trippino , thanks. Confirmation that the list actually should keep order, helps.

Comment: @JonSkeet , the fact that peers indicate that the list actually should not re-order, answers my question :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List actually stays in the order it is filled. If you are facing other behaviors probably you are doing something wrong with your list.

Comment: After some interesting bug hunting, I have found that in some rare cases, I added a rogue control to the wrong control grouping, in such a way that it made the list of objects look out of order, when in fact the controls on the page were out of order. As trippino suggested, code error on my side.